# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I have the following code in `<head>` which basically opens a popup window when a link with the class `.social-button` is clicked:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.social-button').click(function () {
            var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=1,height=470,width=570');
            if (window.focus) {
                NWin.focus();
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code works, however, I´m getting this error message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready(...) is not a function

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Which line exactly throws that error? You have `jQuery()` in the code but the error message says `$()`.

Comment: what is the `$` inside `function ($)` supposed to do?

Comment: @Aziz It aliases `jQuery` to `$` even if `$` isn't available in the global scope.

Answer (score -2):

Replace `JQuery` by `$`  on your first javascript line

Comment: thanks for the quick answear , i modified the code '$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.social-button').click(function () {
        var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=1,height=470,width=570');
        if (window.focus) {
            NWin.focus();
        }
        return false;
    });
});' now on JSHint i get undefined variable $